# highcharts: when adding new data series add new Y axis only if the title is different from existing Y axis

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts

The following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvaGt/) example shows adding a second yAxis and data series to an existing highstock plot. I want to add another axis only if the units type on the previous axis (chart.yAxis[0].title.text) is different. So for example all successive calls to add axis should recognise that the YAxis label has temperature and add the series to the already existing axis and not create another axis. However I am stuck on even getting the name from the axis, for example when I call the following

```
     alert(chart.yAxis[0].title.text);
```

just inside the click the event handler function, the title property is undefined. Anyone know what's going wrong here or how best to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yAxis title is in the chart options.

```
alert(chart.options.yAxis[0].title.text);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4xuoo5te/2/

Comment: actually when the axis is added dynamically the value for text is null